# dotdotdot plugin parses angular expression before its evaluated

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have this code

```
<div ng-app="m" ng-controller="a">
        <div d style="width:100px;height:200px" >
            {{customer.name}} 
           <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy textLorem Ipsum is simply dummy textLorem Ipsum is simply dummy textLorem Ipsum is simply dummy textLorem Ipsum is simply dummy textLorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

here is the JS code

```
var b = angular.module('m', []).controller('a', function ($scope) {
    $scope.customer = {
        name: 'Aby'
    } }); b.directive('d', function () {
    return {
        retistric: 'A',
        link: function ($scope, element, attributes) {
            $(element).dotdotdot({
                /*  The text to add as ellipsis. */
                'ellipsis': '... ',

                /*  jQuery-selector for the element to keep and put after the ellipsis. */
                'after': null,

                /*  Whether to update the ellipsis: true/'window' */
                'watch': true,

                /*  Optionally set a max-height, if null, the height will be measured. */
                'height': null,

                /*  Callback function that is fired after the ellipsis is added,
                    receives two parameters: isTruncated(boolean), orgContent(string). */
                'callback': attributes["callback"],
            });

        }
    };
     });
```

Here is the out put

```
{{customer.name}} Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy textLorem Ipsum is...
```

Here dotdotdot  call sees the angularjs expression as string. How can I make sure that expression is evaluated before plugin act on it?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing link to compile in directive.

```
var b = angular.module('m', []).controller('a', function ($scope) {
  $scope.customer = {
    name: 'Aby'
  } }); b.directive('d', function () {
  return {
    retistric: 'A',
    compile: function (element, attributes) {
      return {
        post: function ($scope, element) {
          $(element).dotdotdot({
            /*  The text to add as ellipsis. */
            'ellipsis': '... ',

            /*  jQuery-selector for the element to keep and put after the ellipsis. */
            'after': null,

            /*  Whether to update the ellipsis: true/'window' */
            'watch': true,

            /*  Optionally set a max-height, if null, the height will be measured. */
            'height': null,

            /*  Callback function that is fired after the ellipsis is added,
             receives two parameters: isTruncated(boolean), orgContent(string). */
            'callback': attributes["callback"]
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```